# Как интегрировать платежную систему в telegram bot на java?

Tags: java, html, telegram-bot, telebot, платежи

Я пишу telegram bot на языке java и пытаясь внедрить систему оплаты. Я столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами, а именно: В основном все платежные провайдеры (Юкасса, Тинкофф, Сбербанк и тд) не имеют API для java, и иза этой проблемы возникает слудующая, более локальная, это payments 2.0 от телеграм. Моя попытка вставить [эта](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/README_RU.md#%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8) в мой код увенчалась провалом, которая скорее всего связана с моей рассеянностью и невнимательностью. Вставив [пример кода payment](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/README_RU.md#%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8) в свой, меня ожидали одни ошибки связанные с SendResponse, bot.execute, chatID, pay() и тп. Они помечены красным, а их природу и причину я не знаю.
[image: Проблемный фрагмент]
Помогите пожалуйста решением этой проблемы, уже неделю с этим мучаюсь.
Вот весь код бота:
`

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)
{
    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {

        String textLine = update.getMessage().getText();
        long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();
        if ((textLine == null) || (textLine.length() < 1))
            textLine = MagicStrings.null_input;
        String request = textLine;
        ///////Just for Log memes :p Disabled by default
        if (MagicBooleans.trace_mode)
            System.out.println("STATE=" + request + ":THAT=" + ((History) chatSession.thatHistory.get(0)).get(0) + ":TOPIC=" + chatSession.predicates.get("topic"));
        else if (request.equals("/start")) {
            response=" ";
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("Hello!");
            // Create ReplyKeyboardMarkup object
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            keyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
            // Create the keyboard (list of keyboard rows)
            List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
            // Create a keyboard row
            KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
            // Set each button, you can also use KeyboardButton objects if you need something else than text
            row.add("/Email");
            row.add("/Buy");
            // Add the first row to the keyboard
            keyboard.add(row);

            keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            // Add it to the message
            message.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);
            try {
                sendMessage(message); // Sending our message object to user
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        else if(request.contains("/Email") ||request.contains("/Buy")) {

            {

                response=" ";
                if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/Email")) {
                    SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object
                            .setChatId(chat_id)
                            .setText("Thank you so much for leaving feedback on me. It means a lot to my creators and to me.");
                    InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
                    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline = new ArrayList<>();
                    rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setUrl("https://mail.google.com").setCallbackData("Feed Back").setText("Email"));
                    // Set the keyboard to the markup
                    rowsInline.add(rowInline);
                    // Add it to the message
                    markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
                    message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
                    try {
                        sendMessage(message); // Sending our message object to user
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/Buy")) {
                SendMessage message = new SendMessage(); // Create a message object object
                    SendResponse response = bot.execute(new SendInvoice(chatID, "title", "desc", "my_payload",
                            "284685063:TEST:NThlNWQ3NDk0ZDQ5", "my_start_param", "USD", new LabeledPrice("label", 200))
                            .providerData("{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}")
                            .photoUrl("https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png").photoSize(100).photoHeight(100).photoWidth(100)
                            .needPhoneNumber(true).needShippingAddress(true).needEmail(true).needName(true)
                            .isFlexible(true)
                            .replyMarkup(new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new InlineKeyboardButton[]{
                                    new InlineKeyboardButton("just pay").pay(),
                                    new InlineKeyboardButton("google it").url("www.google.com")
                            }))
                    );
                    InvoiceCheck.check(response.message().invoice());
                }

                try {
                    sendMessage(message); // Sending our message object to user
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}

        } else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            // Set variables
            String call_data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
            long message_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();
            long chat_id1 = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();
            response=" ";
            if (call_data.equals("Email")) {
                String answer = "Updated message text";
                EditMessageText new_message = new EditMessageText()
                        .setChatId(chat_id1)
                        .setMessageId(toIntExact(message_id))
                        .setText(answer);
                try {
                    editMessageText(new_message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }else if(request.equals("/help"))
        {
            response="What's wrong man? ";
        }
        else
        {
            response = chatSession.multisentenceRespond(request);
            if(response.contains("<"))
            {
                response="Sorry, there was some error! ";
            }

        }

        SendMessage message = new SendMessage().setChatId(chat_id).setText(response);
        try {
            execute(message);
        }
        catch (TelegramApiException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public String getBotUsername()
{
    return "Talk_to_me_Bot";
}

@Override
public String getBotToken()
{
    return "170925sdzxfhcgvfgcdxy34567-sdvhgsdcwcw";
}

private static String getResourcesPath()
{
    File currDir = new File(".");
    String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(path);
    String resourcesPath = path + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources";
    return resourcesPath;
}
```

}
`